# using 'variable.xyz' format in Python

Tags: python

This is a silly question, but I can't figure it out so I had to ask.

I'm editing some Python code and to avoid getting too complicated, I need to be able to define a new variable along the lines of : Car.store = False.

Variable Car has not been defined in this situation. I know I can do dicts (Car['store'] = False) etc... but it has to be in the format above.

Appreciate any help

Thanks.

Comment: So `Car` hasn't been defined, does it really matter?  i.e. why can't you just define `store`, or `car_store` if you want to be specific?

Comment: In this situation it was try: Car.store = asdf except: Car.store = False. I was trying to add error handling without changing too many variables, which is why Car.store had to be in that specific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to what you want is by adding one extra line (assuming you have defined a class called Car):

```
car = Car()
car.store = False
```

Without the first line you will get an error.

If you want brevity you could set `store` to `False` in `__init__` so that only the first line is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but also check out the namedtuple function in the collections module. It lets you access fields of a tuple as if they were named members of a class, and it's nice when all you want is a C-style "structure". Of course, tuples are immutable so you'd probably have to rearrange your existing code quite a bit; perhaps not the best thing for this example, but maybe keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Example code would look like this: `>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> car = namedtuple('Car', 'store')(store=False)
>>> car`
`Car(store=False)`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try whith this:

```
try:
    car.store = False
except NameError:
    #This means that car doesn't exists
    pass
except AttributeError:
    #This means that car.store doesn't exists
    pass
```

Comment: -1 It is very unlikely that AttributeError will be raised in the circumstances that you describe (unless the class is defined with `__slots__`). Did you actually try this yourself? It would of course happen if you did `foo = car.store` and `car` exists but has no `store` attribute, but that's a completely different scenario.

Comment: Yeah, you're right
You need to add a line to get work that code.

<pre>
try:
    car.store
    car.store = False
except NameError:
    #This means that car doesn't exists
    pass
except AttributeError:
    #This means that car.store doesn't exists
    pass
</pre>

Answer (score -1):

```
car, car.store = car if "car" in locals() else lambda:1, False
```